# How to prevent multiple login on two instances of the browser or using two different machines

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm working on an angular form that submits data to my back-end rest service written using Spring Boot. I need to add a feature whereby the user should not be able to login to the system on two instances of the browser or using two different machine.

I have already configured my sessions for a logged in user but it still doesn't achieve what I need.  I'd like some walk-through or some sample snippet on how to go about this.

Comment: Please add some code/configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As I've understood your question correctly that you want to create single login system. Correct me if I'm wrong.

In the last project I had the same requirement, what I've done to achieve that is, I created the token and save it to redis (in my case) and after that whenever user is login from another machine or in another browser, simply overwrite the previous token with new one. Of course Id should be the unique for every user.

Hope this will help you. Don't have the code right now.

Hope this will helps.